# Getting the contents of <script src=...>

Tags: javascript, html, custom-tag

I'm trying to write my own scripting-language parser in JavaScript using html `<script>` tag with custom `type` attribute. For inline scripts it's easy:

```
<script>
 //JS parser
 function λParse(code){/*...*/}

 var arr = document.querySelectorAll(
  'script[type="application/x-lambdascript"]'
 );

 l=arr.length;
 while(l--){
  λParse(arr[l].textContent);
 }
</script>
```

But it's a bit harder for external scripts. I'm able to get the `src` attribute but that's all.
Is there any **universal** solution of getting the contents of an external file? I know it's probably possible using `XMLHttpRequest` but what about webpages saved on my own computer? Is there any API for it?

Thanks.

Comment: You've answered your own question. Do a request and parse the result.

Comment: `function λ-parse(code){/*...*/}` produces `SyntaxError` because of `-`. You can use underscore `λ_parse` or camel case `λParse`.

Comment: It's not possible to get a file from another domain, that would be a security problem, so browsers don't allow it (unless you use [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)).

Comment: @Oriol thanks, syntax error corrected. I'm not going to use cross-origin scripts - all I need is to get the contents of a script from a html document saved in the same directory of my disk.

Comment: It depends on the `src` of the `<script>`s. `XMLHttpRequest` can request same-origin scripts or cross-origin when the remote server offers permission. Though, you'll generally want to use `http://`, even for files "*saved on [your] own computer*," as `file://` doesn't have an origin to validate.

Comment: @m93a Do you access the html document using `file` scheme? If yes, `XMLHttpRequest` to other local files will work on firefox.

Comment: Yeah, I've got it. It's a pitty @Quentin marked this as a duplicate, I'd post the answer. Yes, it's _de facto_ the same problem but nobody posted the exact code. http://pastebin.com/VJssy2p1

Comment: @m93a — That code won't work. You'll hit the same origin policy as mentioned by Jonathan Lonowski.

Comment: @Quentin As I've already said, it's not for **cross-origin** requests. It works if both html and script files are on the same website or both in a local folder. Ordinary javascript would also fail to run if it's cross-origin.

Comment: @m93a — Most browsers treat any other local file as a different origin, even if they are in the same local directory.

Comment: Chrome, Internet Explorer and Opera (which is three of the top five)

Comment: As for reasons not to do it… "Here, open this email attachment, it is a perfectly harmless HTML document".